# ESP32 BLE: LoadProhibited error when transferring large database via Bluetooth Low Energy

Tags: memory, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32, arduino-c++

I am working on App and API for transferring data from bee-hive accessories.
I have a database aprox. of 5000 records and I need to send them all to the app(10 records a message).
The problem is that when I try to load the data, it might drop on LoadProhibited or not.
It doesn't occur on the same record-stack. I might drop on any record stack(1 - 500).
Also the error occurs somewhere between the code. If I add prints it will complete the method and then fall somewhere between the lines :). I tried to store buffer data in char* and stringstreams, both had the same results.

The method:

```
void ConnectorBLE::SendRequestedData(std::string date_from, std::string date_to, int position)
{
    Serial.print("Position: ");Serial.println(position);
    memset(char_buffer, 0, 600);
    int delay_time = (int)(20.0f * position + 160.5789f);
    if (position == 0)
    {
        int count = DatabaseHandler::GetRequestCount(date_from, date_to); // Get Count of packets
        std::string pcount = std::to_string(count);
        if (pcount.length() < 3)
            pcount = "0" + pcount;
        if (pcount.length() < 3)
            pcount = "0" + pcount;
        SendData(MakeCommand(RESPONSE_DATA, ("000" + pcount).c_str())); // Send Initial packet
    }
    else
    {
        std::string position_ = std::to_string(position);
        if (position_.length() < 3)
            position_ = "0" + position_;
        if (position_.length() < 3)
            position_ = "0" + position_;
        std::string respprefix = "2";
        int state = DatabaseHandler::Select(date_from, date_to, position - 1, char_buffer);
        Serial.println("Sending data");
        SendData_(respprefix + position_); // Send Data packet
        Serial.print("Free Heap: ");
        Serial.println(ESP.getFreeHeap());
    }
    old_message_sent = true;
//This point is OK
}
```

Reeboot log:

Guru Meditation Error: Core  0 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled.

Core  0 register dump:
PC      : 0x4009083c  PS      : 0x00060b30  A0      : 0x801c9619  A1      : 0x3ffdef20
A2      : 0x3ffef7e8  A3      : 0xbaad5678  A4      : 0x00000185  A5      : 0x3ffef7e8
A6      : 0x00000000  A7      : 0x00000018  A8      : 0x00000000  A9      : 0x3ffdeef0
A10     : 0x3ffef7e8  A11     : 0x00001800  A12     : 0x3ffef7e8  A13     : 0x00000001
A14     : 0x00000004  A15     : 0x3ffb6cb0  SAR     : 0x0000000b  EXCCAUSE: 0x0000001c
EXCVADDR: 0xbaad5678  LBEG    : 0x4009083c  LEND    : 0x40090852  LCOUNT  : 0x00000017

Backtrace: 0x40090839:0x3ffdef20 0x401c9616:0x3ffdef30 0x401c96b5:0x3ffdef50 0x401c9744:0x3ffdef70 0x401c9ed5:0x3ffdef90 0x401c9ef9:0x3ffdefc0 0x400d1f61:0x3ffdefe0 0x401fffaf:0x3ffdf0a0 0x4011841a:0x3ffdf0c0 0x4011cc6d:0x3ffdf380 0x4011af45:0x3ffdf3a0 0x4011b331:0x3ffdf400 0x4011a74e:0x3ffdf420 0x40119089:0x3ffdf480 0x40130a9a:0x3ffdf4a0 0x401313ee:0x3ffdf4c0 0x40158a2d:0x3ffdf510 0x4015ab9f:0x3ffdf530

ELF file SHA256: 1b8e826616e53d75

Rebooting...
ets Jul 29 2019 12:21:46

rst:0xc (SW_CPU_RESET),boot:0x13 (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:2
load:0x3fff0030,len:1184
load:0x40078000,len:13104
load:0x40080400,len:3036
entry 0x400805e4

[GitHub Link](https://github.com/JustABenda/ApiBlue-Api)

Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, after a few more hours, I discovered that I miss-typed value -> data.
And for those who also don't know how to debug exceptions on ESP in PIO.
Just add `monitor_filters = esp32_exception_decoder` into platformio.ini